# Not equal (!=) operator not working with correctly char in c++

Tags: c++

This code is not working correctly, please help me. Even though I entered the right character it keeps asking "enter right number". And it does not evaluate the condition.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ch = '0';
    A:
    cout << "enter a Character" << endl;
    cin >> ch;
    if ((ch != 'X')||(ch != 'x'))
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Right Number" << endl;
        goto A;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: specify how it's not working. Does it _always_ or _never_ show the messages?

Comment: please tell us what correctly working means for you.

Comment: You probably need to ignore the `'\n'` character left in the input before you're jumping back to `A:`.

Comment: also, whoever's teaching you C++ should clearly tell you that it is very very very much frowned upon to use `goto`. Don't do that!

Comment: yes I know that using goto is not a good practice but sow times it is necessary and second thing is that by working I means that even if I input the 'X' or 'x' it shows that input is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
    if ((ch != 'X') && (ch != 'x'))
```

instead of

```
  if ((ch != 'X')||(ch != 'x'))
```

Also instead of using `goto` you could use a loop

```
 cout << "enter a Character" << endl;
 cin >> ch;
 while(ch!='X' && ch!='x')
 {
      cout << "Please Enter Right Number" << endl;
      cout << "enter a Character" << endl;
      cin>>ch;
 }
```

Comment: First of all Thanks to all of you. Second sorry I have tried many times but I didn't found the related answer thats why i asked New Question. Just after posting my Q, in a blog I read that != doesn't works with the chat type instead it works with string I have tried this and its working but Is this true that it doesn't works with the char type.

Comment: `!=` very well works with `chars`.Didn't your code work after correction?

Comment: Please explain your answer that why I have to use && instead of ||. Thanks

Comment: @SAIFI369.The program should stop when user enters `X` or `x`.So the program should continue asking for another character if user entered something other than `X` or `x` ie continue if character entered is neither `X` nor `x`.Tell me if that made sense.

Comment: OK What I want to do is that if the character entered is other than X or x then program should ask the user to enter it again. That's it.

Comment: Yes my code works after I made changes that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

`(ch != 'X')||(ch != 'x')` is always `true`, you probably means `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: correct, but duplicate duplicate duplicate duplicate - how many hundreds of these do we have to answer?